# Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION when trying to read value of pointer from another program

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi

I am practicing the use of ReadProcessMemory and one task I have is to read the value of a pointer, and then read the value of the address stored in that pointer.

I can get up to the part of reading the value of the pointer, but every time I try to access the value stored in the address in that pointer, I get `Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`, and I don't know why. I have tried to initialize it via `= new int;` but the error still persists.

Here is the program run:
[image]

Here is my code:

`dummy.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>


// Dummy program
int main()
{
    // Variables
    int varInt = 123456;
    std::string varString = "DefaultString";
    char arrChar[128] = "Long char array right there ->";

    // Pointers
    int* ptr2int = &varInt;
    int** ptr2ptr = &ptr2int;
    int*** ptr2ptr2 = &ptr2ptr;

    // Infinite loop of process
    while (true)
    {
        // Print current process ID
        std::cout << "Process ID: " << GetCurrentProcessId() << std::endl;
        
        // Print varInt's address and value
        std::cout << "varInt " << "(0x" << &varInt << ")" << " = " << varInt << std::endl;
        // Print varStrings's address and value
        std::cout << "varString " << "(0x" << &varString << ")" << " = " << varString << std::endl;
        // Print arrChar's address and value
        std::cout << "arrChar " << "(0x" << &arrChar << ")" << " = " << arrChar << std::endl;
        
        // Same thing as above but for the 3 pointers now
        std::cout << "ptr2int " << "(0x" << &ptr2int << ")" << " = " << ptr2int << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ptr2ptr " << "(0x" << &ptr2ptr << ")" << " = " << ptr2ptr << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ptr2ptr2 " << "(0x" << &ptr2ptr2 << ")" << " = " << ptr2ptr2 << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Press ENTER to print again." << std::endl;
        getchar(); // To pause
        std::cout << "-------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

`reader.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

// Program that reads memory from our dummy program
int main()
{
    int* intRead = new int;

    // Get handle
    HANDLE wHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, 16564);

    // Error checking
    if (wHandle == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR! OpenProcess failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Read process memory
    ReadProcessMemory(wHandle, (LPCVOID)0x00F3F990, &intRead, sizeof(int), NULL);

    // Output new value we read
    std::cout << "New value of intRead buffer is: " << *intRead << std::endl; // Throws exception when dereferencing

    // Close the open process
    CloseHandle(wHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

And the CORE file it generates:

```
[main] reader 1000 (0) exception: trapped!
[main] reader 1000 (0) exception: code 0xC0000005 at 0x401114
[main] reader 1000 (0) exception: ax 0xF3FA48 bx 0x246FF10 cx 0x8EE00000 dx 0x0
[main] reader 1000 (0) exception: si 0x0 di 0x401000 bp 0x246FEF4 sp 0x246FEE0
[main] reader 1000 (0) exception: exception is: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: Stack trace:
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 0: sp = 0x246F2A8, pc = 0x6100A2C3
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 1: sp = 0x246F2E4, pc = 0x77DC8FB2
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 2: sp = 0x246F308, pc = 0x77DC8F84
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 3: sp = 0x246F3D0, pc = 0x77DA71E6
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 4: sp = 0x246FEF4, pc = 0x61004402
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 5: sp = 0x246FF3C, pc = 0x61004420
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 6: sp = 0x246FF48, pc = 0x4131EE
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 7: sp = 0x246FF58, pc = 0x40103A
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 8: sp = 0x246FF74, pc = 0x76736739
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 9: sp = 0x246FF84, pc = 0x77D98FEF
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 10: sp = 0x246FFDC, pc = 0x77D98FBD
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: frame 11: sp = 0x246FFEC, pc = 0x0
[main] reader 1000 (0) stack: End of stack trace
```

Compiled using MinGW.

Comment: Please don't use images of text, you can copy'n'paste the output from the terminal instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just retrieve a pointer with `ReadProcessMemory()` and then dereference it normally, like you would with pointers in your own process.  You have to use `ReadProcessMemory()` for each value you want to read from the remote process.

`0x00F3F990` is the *address* of `ptr2int` in the remote process. You are reading the *value* of `ptr2int` at that address.  That value is the *address* of `varInt` in the remote process.  To then read the *value* of `varInt`, you need to call `ReadProcessMemory()` again with the address that is in `ptr2int`, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

// Program that reads memory from our dummy program
int main()
{
    int varInt;
    int* ptr2int;

    // Get handle
    HANDLE wHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, 16564);

    // Error checking
    if (wHandle == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR! OpenProcess failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Read process memory
    ReadProcessMemory(wHandle, (LPCVOID)0x00F3F990, &ptr2int, sizeof(int*), NULL);

    // Output new value we read
    std::cout << "New value of ptr2int is: " << ptr2int << std::endl;

    // Read process memory
    ReadProcessMemory(wHandle, (LPCVOID)ptr2int, &varInt, sizeof(int), NULL);

    // Output new value we read
    std::cout << "New value of varInt is: " << varInt << std::endl;

    // Close the open process
    CloseHandle(wHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The line

```cpp
ReadProcessMemory(wHandle, (LPCVOID)0x00F3F990, &intRead, sizeof(int), NULL);
```

is telling the API to write what it read to the pointer variable, breaking the pointer.

Change the line to

```cpp
ReadProcessMemory(wHandle, (LPCVOID)0x00F3F990, intRead, sizeof(int), NULL);
```

(remove the `&` before `intRead`)

to have the API write to the allocated buffer.